# ember-simple-auth facebook authenticator

Tags: facebook, authentication, ember.js, ember-simple-auth

Trying to hook up facebook authentication for my app. I've got the backend working correctly but my authenticator (I think this is the problem) is always returning `undefined`.

Copying the example from from [ember-simple-auth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/tests/dummy/app/authenticators/torii.js) the console log on line 23 is never called, making me think something else the issue?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Torii from 'ember-simple-auth/authenticators/torii';

const {inject: {service}} = Ember;

export default Torii.extend({
  torii: service(),
  ajax: service(),

  authenticate() {
    const ajax = this.get('ajax');

    return this._super(...arguments).then((data) => {
      return ajax.request('http://localhost:8080/api/login', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'application/json',
        data: {
          'grant_type': 'facebook_auth_code',
          'auth_code': data.authorizationCode
        }
      }).then((response) => {

        console.log("CALLED!");

        return {
          access_token: response,
          provider: data.provider
        };
      });
    });
  }
});
```

The response from the server is the access_token from facebook;

How can I better debug/solve what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a simple error with the `dataType` used. It should be `dataType: 'json'` not `dataType: 'application/json'`